# .each and callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, cheerio

I am using request and cheerio node modules to create get some data out of a website.
I'd like to get a list of item and once this list is complete, call an asynchronous function:

```
request('http://myurl', function(req,res,data){
    var $ = cheerio.load(data);
    var List = [];

    $('.myItems').each(function(i, element){
        console.log( typeof $(this).text() )
        List.push($(this).text());
    });

   for (var i=0; i <  List.length; i++){
      // make an asynchronous call to a API
   }
});
```

My question is how do I wait for the list to be completed, ie, how can I know than the .each function has looped through all the items?

Can I do this with async?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `.each` function of cheerio is synchronous (see [source](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/master/lib/api/traversing.js#L265)). So as long as you do nothing asynchronous in the callback (which is the case in the question), you have nothing to do : at the following line the loop will be complete.

---

If you *do* call asynchronous functions in the loop, the cleanest and simplest solution is to use a Promise library.

In a sequential way (exemple with [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)) :

```
var p = Promise.resolve();
$('.myItems').each(function(i, element){
    p = p.then(function(){ 
         // do something with $(this).text() and return a promise
    });
});
p.then(function(){
   // all asynchronous tasks are finished
});
```

If sequential requests aren't needed (here an example with [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)) :

```
Q.allSettled($('.myItems').map(function(){
   // return a promise
})).then(function(){
   // all asynchronous tasks are finished
});
```

Comment: I am using the results to do an asynchronous request to another api. That's my problem :(

Comment: Then we need to know more about those requests. Do they need to be synchronous ?

Comment: @Spearfisher Please fix the example in the question, it really looks like you're doing only synchronous operations in the callback of .each

Answer (score 2):

Well, for anyone else having this problem, just know that you don't really need to use the `each` method, you can transform them in an array with the `toArray` method and iterate over them in a `for` loop.

That way, there is no need to use an external lib like Bluebird.

```
request('http://myurl', function(req,res,data){
    var $ = cheerio.load(data);
    var List = [];

    const items = $('.myItems').toArray();
    for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        const el = items[i];
        console.log( typeof $(el).text() )
        List.push($(el).text());
        // make an asynchronous call to a API
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module to easily handle those kinds of async tasks.

Specifically [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) or [async.eachLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) if you need concurrency > 1 or [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries) if you want to go through the items in the array, one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit I haven't managed to get Denys Séguret's solution working (for the async calls within .each() loop) - the "after" operation still happens before the .each() loop is completed, however I found a different way, and I hope it helps someone:

```
var Promises = require('bluebird');

request('http://myurl', function(req,res,data){
    var $ = cheerio.load(data);
    var List = [];

    Promises
    // Use this to iterate serially
    .each($('.myItems').get(), function(el){
        console.log( typeof $(el).text() )
        List.push($(el).text());
    })
    // Use this if order of items is not important
    .map($('.myItems').get(), function(el){
        console.log( typeof $(el).text() )
        List.push($(el).text());
    }, {concurrency:1}) // Control how many items are processed at a time
    // When all of the above are done, following code will be executed
    .then(function(){
        for (var i=0; i <  List.length; i++){
            // make an asynchronous call to a API
        }
    });
});
```

In this particular code example it looks like you could be doing your async calls within then mapping functions, but you get the gist...

Map: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#mapfunction-mapper--object-options---promise

Each: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#eachfunction-iterator---promise